# Using Curl to get tables data

Tags: android, html, parsing, jsoup

I need to parse data from a website, this request gives me the json which I need when I run it in command line, when I tried to transform it to  Android,  it's not working :

> **My request** : "curl 'http://billetterie.ctm.ma/site/select_voyages_aller?datev=21-01-2017&agen_dep=022&agen_dest=745&nbp=1&dater=21-01-2017&aller=AS&tpay=MA&q=1&_search=false&nd=1485004301429&rows=30&page=1&sidx=&sord='
>   -H 'Host: billetterie.ctm.ma' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:50.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/50.0' -H
>   'Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01' -H
>   'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5' --compressed -H 'X-Requested-With:
>   XMLHttpRequest' -H 'Referer:
>   http://billetterie.ctm.ma/site/get_voyages?nat=1&tov1=nat&aller=AS&ag_dep=022&ag_arr=745&datev=21-01-2017&dater=21-01-2017&nbp=1&tpay=MA&horr=non'
>   -H 'Cookie: __utma=155676777.794288111.1468961313.1473110615.1483191519.26; __utmz=155676777.1472508246.19.2.utmcsr=billetterie.ctm.ma|utmccn=(referral)|utmcmd=referral|utmcct=/site/accueil_widget;
>   SESSb32ad49581ba1927701cb25c04e30aae=VhEOkLJ2qmLrlxEW3sNRIFpnS0ZUYPGUwAyvVqui_9I;
>   _ctm_site_session=BAh7BzoQX2NzcmZfdG9rZW4iMUJ1ZzFpN3JDdGlzaTJGZUZEY2F0SWZPK3hMOWhwWW1vSFJ5QnoyUXFWLzA9Og9zZXNzaW9uX2lkIiUwNmMxOTYxNGIzOTRmNzY2ZWY0YzkyYTVjNTc4MzQzYQ%3D%3D--59c0a57e5935d23668767649d8483155f719faf8'
>   -H 'Connection: keep-alive'";

My code on Java is :

```
 public static String getRequest(String url) {
        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer("");
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
        try {
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet();

            URI uri = new URI(url);
            httpGet.setURI(uri);


            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            InputStream inputStream = httpResponse.getEntity().getContent();
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    inputStream));

            String readLine = bufferedReader.readLine();
            while (readLine != null) {
                stringBuffer.append(readLine);
                stringBuffer.append("\n");
                readLine = bufferedReader.readLine();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        } finally {
            if (bufferedReader != null) {
                try {
                    bufferedReader.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO: handle exception
                }
            }
        }
        return stringBuffer.toString();

    }
```

Comment: what does it parse? and where do you init url variable?

Comment: I init url variables before starting this Thread, I found only titles and same paragraph not tables like the link in my navigator, I hope I answered your question

Comment: it seems that data into table is loaded asyncronously. you can see the loader if you open your link. With jsoup you don't wait for asyncronous calls, so your table is empty or not created yet

Comment: Yes you are right dude, so look my edit and tell me what do you think

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't parse this page syncronously, it's not JSOUP problem or HttpClient problem.

The only way I can think is to explore your link page and to make yourself the request done asyncronously in that page. If what you need is table content what you need to parse is not starting page.

What you need is to find what async call is done to populate that table on the browser, make that call and try to parse the response

Comment: but bro, If you run the request above, you can get json of response, the problem now is running curl in android

Comment: I think you should use NDK approach. Or maybe some libraries?

Comment: Ok, but for me the simplest approach is to make only inner call, so you can use JSOUP and its fantastic features. Is too complex to identify the correct request to make?

Comment: Yes, u are right, really I'm blocked here, because there is a lot of options whith this curl request, if you found something, could you comment it here ?

Comment: Oh ok, I'm understanding now: requesting only table data results in a JSON, so you are searching a way to parse these data?

Comment: My probelem, I can't get data table on android, if I get it parsing it's easy for me.

Comment: repost your initiali link please

Comment: http://billetterie.ctm.ma/site/get_voyages?nat=1&tov1=nat&aller=AS&ag_dep=022&ag_arr=745&datev=21-01-2017&dater=21-01-2017&nbp=1&tpay=MA&horr=non

Comment: ok, now understood, your way to try to make a request similar to curl one is a good way, sorry I don't know how to help you more